# Pointer in func parameter: copy by value or by pointer

Tags: pointers, go

here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func double(x *int) {
    fmt.Printf("pointer of pointer #1: %p\n", &x)
    fmt.Printf("pointer#1 : %p\n", x)

    *x += *x
    x = nil
    fmt.Printf("pointer#2 : %p\n", x)
    fmt.Printf("pointer of pointer #2: %p\n", &x)

}

func main() {
    var a = 3
    double(&a)
    fmt.Println(a) // 6
    fmt.Printf("pointer a in main: %p\n", &a)

    p := &a
    double(p)
    fmt.Println(a, p == nil) // 12 false
    fmt.Printf("pointer p in main: %p\n", p)
    fmt.Printf("pointer of pointer p in main: %p\n", &p)

}
```

or in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/da1vnBd5JEx).

Question 1: pointer parameters in functions get copy of pointer or get directly pointer?

Question 2: why value *x* in **double** function is the same as *&a* in **main** func?

Question 3: if *x* has the same value as *&a* then why when *x = nil* *&a* stil has value and not nil?

Comment: Q1. copy of pointer. Q2. because that's what copy does/means. Q3. because of 1.

Comment: Go is simple, every assignment is a copy.

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: pointer parameters in functions get copy of pointer or get directly pointer?

The distinction this question is trying to make suggests a certain lack of background understanding.

Think of a pointer as a number / address which can be used to access some other data. A copy of this address just copies a number. Is 42 the same as a "copy of 42"? Yes, in a sense.

```
x := &value // x holds the address of value now
y := x      // and now y does, too
```

Given the above two lines, assigning `x` to something else does absolutely nothing to change `value` or `&value`. It simply reassigns `x` to another address. However, doing something like `*x = 999` changes `value` itself because `x` holds the address of `value` and the redirection `*x` means access to `value`.

If this isn't 100% clear, try to work through the [Tour of Go starting here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1).

> Question 2: why value x in double function is the same as &a in main func?

Because of the explanation above. `&a` is the address of `a` - it's a number, think 42 again (the real address is something like 0x40e020, but let's call it 42 for simplicity). When you pass it into a function accepting a `*int`, 42 gets copied and `x` in `double` becomes 42. Now both `x` inside `double` and `&a` outside it have the address of `a` in them.

> Question 3: if x has the same value as &a then why when x = nil &a stil has value and not nil?

Because `x` just has the value 42 in it, which happens to be the address of `a`. If you assign anything else to `x`, that doesn't change *the address of a*, does it? It changes `x`. `x` will no longer point to `a`.